# error found when loading /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

This error :

[image]

So for some context, i was stupid and noob I downloaded katoolin in my ubuntu 20.04 and forgot the warning of removing them before upgrading/updating, so they caused my system to crash i can’t boot at all, i tried every command i found regarding this matter none seemed to work, i already uninstalled katoolin, fixed broken pkgs, i’ve also run thru some key_recovery problem and its all gone now, and when i update/upgrade it seems like i have done it successfully no uninstalled or not upgraded packages or pkgs that need to be removed, all is nice until i reboot the kali menu appears as if it’s a kali system and not an ubuntu one, and i have no idea what to do next, btw i’ve also tried to remove kali-menu and it worked now it say’s no kali menu is there to be removed so what do i do now to get my system back any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to text terminal using `<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F5>`, login to it and reinstall official package with [needed */usr/bin/locale-check* file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=locale-check) by using command below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall base-files=11ubuntu5.3
```

then reboot.